# Different logins for page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, roles

I was wondering if you guys could help me explain how and where (im guessing sitemaster) to make different logins using ASP.NET in c#.

I'd like to create a page for administrator to use and a page for normal users to use.

Let's say, when administrator logs in, it offers him sub-pages where he can add books to "online library", add new users in application, and when the user logs in, it offers him to book a book, or to buy a book from library.

So when administrator logs in, the page is adjusted to his rights (users don't see the same page), and when users log in, they see a different page, adjusted to their rights.

Any links, tutorial, or help is appreciated.

Comment: This is basic functionality of any user/role based authentication system and there are many solutions for ASP.NET. If you do some research you will find a lot of indroductions and tutorials online.

Comment: i've not used asp for a while but i guess you are looking for something like this http://tutorials.studentwebserver.co.uk/dotNETTutorial/security/default.aspx

Comment: Essentially, yes, that link will help you develop a suitable user role based authentication system. You may want to take a gander at these sites too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the following steps:

1) create a page where a gridview with two columns one is for pages another contains checkboxes.
(checked pages will be allowed)

2) create a datatable in sql add & update the pages allowed according to the username and type.

3) now come to the main page where all the menus are available. after the logging in give the condition for administrator and users
(for this you have to give conditions at the design page. for permitted pages enable the menuitems and for others disable them.

Its just the idea. based on this you just develop it.